# Padding a alphanumeric textbox text with zero's

Tags: c#

when a `textbox` contains only digits I am using `padleft` method,here my `textbox` contains alphanumeric text,for this I need to do padding with zero's.

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(5, '0');
```

This line works when `textbox` contains digits like 1.output is 00001.
Now if my text in textbox is A1.output should be A00001.
if AB1 Output should be AB00001.
the number of digits should be 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegEx` for this:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, "(\\d+)");
textBox1.Text = parts.Length<2 ? parts[0] : parts[0] + parts[1].PadLeft(5, '0');
```

**Update**: if you don't want to use `Regex`, you can try the following code:

```
int i = 0;
for(;i < textBox1.TextLength; i++){
  if(char.IsDigit(textBox1.Text[i])) break;
}
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0,i) + 
                textBox1.Text.Substring(i).PadLeft(5,'0');
```

Comment: Its working but total number of digits should be 5, like this,when I entered AB1,AB00001 should be the output

Comment: @user2897388 It was because your question was wrong, now you edited it and the answer is much simpler, see the update.

Comment: can you explain me without using Regular Expression for the same process

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42499/discussion-between-user2897388-and-king-king)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I assumed you wanted to split letters from numbers. It will also work if you have only digits or numbers.

```
string input = "A1";

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)");

string group1 = match.Groups.Count > 1 ? match.Groups[1].Value : "";
string group2 = match.Groups.Count > 2 ? match.Groups[2].Value : "";

string output = group1 + group2.PadLeft(6 - group1.Length - group2.Length, '0');
```